# when to choose ASP.NET and When PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net

I am not here to add another subjective question.

I know that many developers are using only ASP.NET and others Only PHP......

in my case where my team uses both, of course more advanced in one,

I like to know the keys to choose one ? can you guys list all the Pros, and cons for those language? I know both are good, Dont be BIASED.

answers for other langauges are welcomed.

I will add one pro  for DOTNET: C# is used for all kind of developments( Web, windows..)

Comment: @Eric: as is ASP.NET/Visual Studio. *Linux* is free, where as Windows is not, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @Dean I think he meant "free as in freedom".

Comment: @Artefacto: Why would we care, as users of the tool?

Comment: @Billy You can fix bugs yourself, for instance.

Comment: @Artefacto You actually get the source with asp.net mvc.

Comment: @Eric: as Dean said, ASP.net/Visual Studio is free... And so is the mono framework if linux is your thing.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427136/when-to-choose-lamp-over-asp-net

Comment: @Artefacto: Err, if the average web developer was qualified to fix bugs in something like PHP, then they'd probably not be a web developer in the first place.

Comment: Are you saying ASP.Net webforms or MVC?

Comment: @Billy Probably not the average web developer, but anyone with an average grasp of C and a few weeks exploring the source code would be qualified to fix at least 20% of the bugs (if not more).

Comment: Realistically it doesn't matter much that it's possible to fix bugs in PHP yourself. Doing so you'd either be dependent upon a custom compiled version of PHP (negates the big advantage of portability), or you'd have to wait for your patch to make its way through the release cycle *and* for your host to update their PHP version (takes ages). In the end you'll usually just file a bug report and use a workaround, the same way you'd do for MS technologies. I still like open source PHP better, simply because I believe platforms I build upon should not be controlled by a single vendor. `</rant>` :)

Comment: @deceze It doesn't negate portability... except if your fix is no portable. Obviously, this would only work for internal PHP applications, where you usually have your distribution channel (deb/rpm repository). But there also may other advantages besides fixing bugs. Facebook wouldn't have been able to write HipHop if PHP weren't so liberally licensed, for instance. I don't deny that these advantages are only relevant once you're a serious power user, but I dismiss the "it's not an advantage because most people won't benefit from it" argument (in this case accompanied by "web devs are stupid")

Comment: @Artefacto I absolutely agree that Billy's "web devs are stupid" argument is uncalled for and insulting. That aside, I'm not quite following your "except if the fix is not portable" argument. A fix for a bug in the PHP core doesn't seem very easily portable to me.

Comment: @deceze By portable I assumed you meant "portable between operating systems". Apparently you meant something else.

Comment: @Artefacto I meant if I were to develop an application in PHP and find a bug in PHP, say `in_array` didn't work as expected, and I were to fix the bug in the PHP core to make `in_array` work as expected, now my application would be dependent upon this fix, which only existed in my custom version of PHP. I could not take my PHP application and run it elsewhere, which is what you usually want to do with a PHP app. So yes, I *can* fix bugs in PHP myself, but realistically that doesn't help me at all immediately. Maybe if you're working on a Facebook level it would.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are good systems on their accord. Apparently Asp.Net has the advantage of being able to utilize a more mature platform, and better languages (f# - but it's personal taste), and PHP has more world ready open source applications. But these does not answer which one to use in a project.

It depends on many factors. For example:

- Size of the project (PHP might be better for small size quick solutions)
- Size of any existing codebase
- Requirements of the client (or boss, etc).
- Deployment environment (Asp.Net is not good on Linux)
- Risks (Asp.Net comes with very good anti injection mechanisms, for PHP you'd need consistent use PEAR libraries)
- Availability of programmers on your team

Baseline: It's generally a business decision, not a technical one.

Comment: +1 for "It's generally a business decision, not a techical one."

Comment: +1 for a well rounded answer that doesn't descend into FUD on either side.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered a thousand times over.

As with any language decision, the experience of your team is the biggest influence.

If you want easy to outsource code and come from a scripting background (e.g. front-end devs doing the odd code snippet back-end modify) I'd back PHP.

PHP pros:

- Cost advantages.
- More existing code (e.g. Wordpress).
- Greater level of online support.
- Easier to find new "coders".
- Quick to get going.
- Great for small projects.

PHP cons:

- Writing bulletproof code is tougher.
- Debugging cost is pretty high. Perhaps tooling helps this one.

If you have developers who were brought up on VB.Net or are recent uni graduates without any web experience/mentality then ASP.NET is a definite possibility.

ASP.NET pros:

- Quick drag-and-drop controls.
- Pseudo-hides the web page cycle from developers who are not web-friendly.
- C# is a much nicer language than PHP. VB.NET is perhaps too.
- Validation and AJAX are pretty easy.

ASP.NET cons:

- If you know the web then ASP.NET can get in the way.
- The cost if you move to an enterprise level can be larger, but for the most part there are various legitimate ways to get discounted or often free software under Microsoft programs.
- Harder to find cheap labour.
- Often obscure bugs related to leaky abstractions.

If you have developers who know what they're doing on the web, and are decent coders too (a programming background) then ASP.NET MVC is the way to go.

ASP.NET MVC pros:

- Gets out of your way / minimalist approaches to code and markup.
- Minimal bugs and typically easy to correct the ones that exist.
- Highly testable.
- Highly modular (can write views as PHP style code if you wanted, or HAML or anything).

ASP.NET MVC cons:

- No drag-and-drop controls (same as PHP).
- The cost is the same as ASP.NET.
- Harder to find coders (you'll probably be training someone with talent at this stage).
- Combined Client+Server validation still feels like it's getting there, but it's on par with PHP at least and there's a lot of cool auto-binding.

Comment: "C# is a much nicer language than PHP. VB.NET is perhaps too." let the wars begin

Comment: @Earlz, yeah let that one slip. Still I can't imagine many programmers arguing that C# isn't nicer than PHP for your particular measure of nice. Most people only hate C# because Microsoft are behind it.

Comment: I think we can all agree that it's an accomplishment for a language to be worse than PHP. And that comes from a (mainly) PHP coder who wouldn't touch the Microsoft development universe with a ten foot pole. ;)

Comment: @deceze: Well, I don't know. There is ECMAScript.....

Comment: And perl. PHP doesn't look like cursing, at least.

Comment: @Billy I actually think that ECMAScript as a language is leagues better than PHP. What sucks about it is the environment it's usually run in. The few flaws it has (like optional `;`'s, `+` for concatenation) are insignificant compared to the verbose pile of retroactively tacked on features that PHP is.

Answer (score 0):

just want to add that asp.net works perfectly fine on Linux and MacOS Server under Mono. We use it in production without issues.